# OpenCV 3.4.3 throwing (-212) parsing error exception (icvXMLParseTag)

Tags: c++, opencv, xml-parsing

I compiled OpenCV v3.4.3 with some custom arguments; static linking, 1394 driver not included and release build, see below:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -D WITH_1394=OFF -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

I have a custom program to compile haar cascade files into a header file, this is for file portability since I cannot have any asset files and everything has to be bundled into one binary, the below will produce the header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    string fn = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
    ifstream in(fn.c_str());
    string all,line;
    while (getline(in,line))
        all += line + "\n";

    ofstream out("opencv_data.h");
    out << "const char xml[] = {";
    for (size_t i=0; i<all.length(); i++) {
        if (i%16==0) out << "\n";
        out << int(all[i]) << ", ";
    }
    out << "10};\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using FileStorage (FileStorage::READ | FileStorage::MEMORY) to read the pre-produced header byte array into OpenCV, see incomplete example below:

```
#include "opencv_data.h"
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
FileStorage fs(xml, FileStorage::READ | FileStorage::MEMORY);
face_cascade.read(fs.getFirstTopLevelNode()
```

This is **working fine** when compiled on macOS 10.13.6 using libc++, the problem is when compiling on Linux, standard Debian 9.4 machine compiled using g++ and static linking (-static-libstdc++) -- the binary will throw an **XML parsing error**, see below:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(3.4.3) /root/opencv-3.4.3/modules/core/src/persistence_xml.cpp:474: error: (-212:Parsing error) icvXMLParseTag in function '(null)(24352): Tag should start with '<''

Aborted
```

The debian 9.4 build works normally if I manually pull the cascade file into the program at runtime (include it as an external asset and load as a .xml file) but fails to work properly when loading via memory (via header byte array)

Cheers.